# If and How to publish application packages to pub?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I understand that I can publish my packages, 
and every project including a pubspec file is automatically a package.

When I want to publish my application package it tell's me, I need a 'lib' folder, but I thought 'lib is only for library packages...

Now I am not sure if I should add the empty 'lib' and publish or if there is another way for application packages.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of current implementation.

When the `'pub'` manager publish your package on `pub.dartlang.org` it assume that you publish not `application` but public `library collection`.

`Library collection` requires at least one `library` in package.

By convention libraries resides in `'lib'` directory.

If you have `library` (under the current rules you should have it) it means that you have it in `'lib'` directory.

If this (`lib`) directory does not found in your package (also include at least one `library`) then your package assumed broken (or has non conventional directory layout).

This limitation prevent publish similar packages (without `libraries`).

Comment: So you would advise me to just create an empty `lib` folder? currently I have my user scripts  in `bin` and my non user scripts in `tool`

Comment: @H.R. You must create `'lib'` directory and put to it `dummy` library (that not exports `nothing`). Dart recommended call it `"you_package_name.dart"` but you can call it `'dummy.dart'`.